# CSS blur filter on 3D transformed elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms, css-filters

```js
document.querySelector( 'style' ).innerHTML += `
  hr:nth-of-type( 1 ) {
    transform: translateZ( calc( var( --mid ) * 1rem ) );
  }
  hr:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
    transform: translateZ( calc( var( --mid ) * -1rem ) );
  }
  hr:nth-of-type( 3 ) {
    transform: rotateY( 90deg ) translateZ( calc( var( --mid ) * 1rem ) );
  }
  .rotate_y, .rotate_x, hr {
    animation-name: rotateY;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rotateY {
    0% {
      transform: rotateY( 0deg );
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateY( 360deg );
    }  
  }
  .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateX;
  }
  @keyframes rotateX {
    0% { transform: rotateX( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateX( 360deg ); }  
  }
`
```

```css
:root {
  --long: 6;
  --mid: calc( var( --long ) / 2 );
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0rem; padding: 0rem;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
body, section, div, span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
body {
  perspective: calc( var( --long ) * 3rem )
}
span:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg ) rotateX( calc( 90deg ) );
}
span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.25rem #000 inset;
}
section, hr {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.25rem #444 inset;
  border-style: none;
  width: calc( var( --long ) * 1rem ); height: calc( var( --long ) * 1rem );
  background-color: rgba( 200, 200, 200, 0.9 );
}
section {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0rem transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<style>
  hr {
    animation-name: brightness;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  
    animation-direction: alternate;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 1 ) hr:nth-of-type( 1 ) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 1 ) hr:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 1 ) hr:nth-of-type( 3 ),
  span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr:nth-of-type( 3 ) {   
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr:nth-of-type( 1 ), 
  span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  @keyframes brightness {
    0% { filter: brightness( 110% ); }
    50% { filter: brightness( 50% ); }
    100% { filter: brightness( 110% ); }    
  }
  hr{ filter: blur( 0.5rem ); }
</style>
<section class='rotate_x'>
  <div class='rotate_y'>
    <span> <hr><hr><hr> </span> <span> <hr><hr><hr> </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

In chrome this cube starts off blurred then quickly reverts back to it's appearance before blur; ignoring this line:

`hr{ filter: blur( 0.5rem ); }`

Here is a gif below that demonstrates what it looks like:
[image]

**The aim is to blur the faces of a 3D transformed element. How can I achieve this with Vanilla CSS?**

*I first attempted blurring the cube element as a whole which fully broke the illusion. Here I am trying to blur each `hr` or "face" individually. Still without the desired result*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the cube in another container that doesn't has any 3D transform applied to it, let's say `.cube`:

```html
<section class='cube'>
  <section class='rotate_x'>
    <div class='rotate_y'>
      <span> <hr><hr><hr> </span> <span> <hr><hr><hr> </span>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Then you can apply filter animation to it without any issue:

Also you need to move `perspective: calc( var( --long ) * 3rem );` from `body` to the `.cube` element itself.

```css
.cube{ 
  animation: focus 3s linear both alternate;
  perspective: calc( var( --long ) * 3rem );
}
@keyframes focus {
  from {
    filter: blur( 0.5rem );
  }
  
  to {
    filter: blur( 0rem );
  }
}
```

```js
document.querySelector( 'style' ).innerHTML += `
  hr:nth-of-type( 1 ) {
    transform: translateZ( calc( var( --mid ) * 1rem ) );
  }
  hr:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
    transform: translateZ( calc( var( --mid ) * -1rem ) );
  }
  hr:nth-of-type( 3 ) {
    transform: rotateY( 90deg ) translateZ( calc( var( --mid ) * 1rem ) );
  }
  .rotate_y, .rotate_x, hr {
    animation-name: rotateY;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rotateY {
    0% {
      transform: rotateY( 0deg );
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateY( 360deg );
    }  
  }
  .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateX;
  }
  @keyframes rotateX {
    0% { transform: rotateX( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateX( 360deg ); }  
  }
`
```

```css
:root {
  --long: 6;
  --mid: calc( var( --long ) / 2 );
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0rem; padding: 0rem;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
body, section, div, span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
span:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg ) rotateX( calc( 90deg ) );
}
span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.25rem #000 inset;
}
section, hr {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.25rem #444 inset;
  border-style: none;
  width: calc( var( --long ) * 1rem ); height: calc( var( --long ) * 1rem );
  background-color: rgba( 200, 200, 200, 0.9 );
}
section {
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0rem transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.cube{ 
  animation: focus 3s linear both alternate;
  perspective: calc( var( --long ) * 3rem );
}
  
@keyframes focus {
  from {
    filter: blur( 0.5rem );
  }
  
  to {
    filter: blur( 0rem );
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  hr {
    animation-name: brightness;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  
    animation-direction: alternate;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 1 ) hr:nth-of-type( 1 ) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 1 ) hr:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 1 ) hr:nth-of-type( 3 ),
  span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr:nth-of-type( 3 ) {   
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr:nth-of-type( 1 ), 
  span:nth-of-type( 2 ) hr:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  @keyframes brightness {
    0% { filter: brightness( 110% ); }
    50% { filter: brightness( 50% ); }
    100% { filter: brightness( 110% ); }    
  }
</style>
<section class='cube'>
  <section class='rotate_x'>
    <div class='rotate_y'>
      <span> <hr><hr><hr> </span> <span> <hr><hr><hr> </span>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: good solution. just seems to completely flatten on chrome with this answer. `perspective:..` seems ignored

Comment: @devsandbox Oops, just fixed it, please check.

Comment: Great edit. Seemed to fix the problem. And I realized just now the actual problem with my code is I'm overwriting the `filter: brightness()` from my keyframed animation. Explains why Chrome shows blurred at first before the animation "loads" I guess. That's the problem I created :( lol. But this is a great solution too so I'm accepting.